# MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification in the background

Tags: ios, background-process, nsnotificationcenter, mpmusicplayercontroller, nsnotification

Whenever I play a track and then move to the background, I can't get either of these notifications to fire in my app. Does anyone know why or how?

```
        self.player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
        [self.player beginGeneratingPlaybackNotifications];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handlePlaybackStateChanged:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.player ];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleItemChanged:) name:MPMusicPlayerControllerNowPlayingItemDidChangeNotification object:self.player ];
```

Comment: Enable  background audio mode **(Project settings > Capabilities > Background modes > Audio and AirPlay)**

Answer (score 1):

Add below code

```
UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask = 0;
UIApplication  *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
bgTask = [app beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
    [app endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
}];
```

in your AppDelegate's `applicationDidEnterBackground` method, then your methods will work in BackGround also.

Also Enable

> Audio, Airplay and Picture in Picture

from Capabilities. See the screenshot

[image]

Comment: I'm running into a new problem now. When this notification fires in the background, I run some code to play a different mp3 using AVPlayer. For some reason though the song doesn't play. In the foreground it plays fine. I also have no problem playing from the AVPlayer in the background, but something about the switch from MPMuiscPlayerController to AVPlayer in the background breaks it.